# 今日以前に設定できないようにしたはずなのに、今日まで設定できなくなる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

投稿で投稿のアップ期間を設定出来るようにしているんですが、投稿の開始する日を今日以前に設定できないようにコードを書いたのですが、何故か今日までが設定できないようになっており、<や<=など工夫しているのですが、うまい事今日投稿できるように修正できません。
大なり小なりなどの設定がおかしいのでしょうか。それとも日時のデータが悪いのでしょうか？

設定箇所
plan.rb

```
def date_before_start
      errors.add(:start_on, "は今日より後の日付を登録してください。") unless
      Time.current <= self.start_on 
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

もし `self.start_on` に入っているのが時刻ではなく日付なのであるなら、`Time.current` ではなく `Date.current` を使ってみてください。

`Time.current` だと時刻情報も含めたデータが返ってくるため、0 時 0 分以外は `Time.current` の方が大きくなってしまいます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまく制限を掛けれました。